# Knowing if a given url is a page url (not static file)

Tags: asp.net, url

Is there a way to know if a given url is a url of page, not of a static file?

I need it to download content from given url and I dont want to download big video file with appended  .php extension.

Comment: It is really unclear - can you give a few examples?

Comment: why don't you filter by extension?

Comment: Ok.I want allow users save html content of some pages from other sites - not some .zip files or images.

Comment: @AntonPutov: Have a look at [Validate URL programmatically using asp.net C#](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread6509-validate-url-programmatically-using-aspnet-csharp.aspx)

Comment: we need more details, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I dont want filter by extensions beckause big video file can be appended .php extension

Comment: can anybody explained why this question was downwoted!? what is unclear in my words?I need this answer beckause I dont want upload in a database big file specifyed by malious user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the URL of a page doesn't say anything about its content. A URL ending on .html might contain HTML or anything else.
The only (mostly) reliable reference you have is the value of the `Content-Type` HTTP header (e.g. for HTML is should be `text/html` or in case of XHTML it might also be `application/xhtml+xml`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use: **[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)**

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://yoursite.com/anypage.aspx", @"C:\anyfile.html");

    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/anypage.aspx");
}
```